# How to restore mysql database from `.ibd `files?

Tags: mysql

I upgraded my 18.04 to a 20.04 and I had a big crash on the Mysql update. Mysql was updated to 8.0 but with a failure. I was unable neither to start Mysql nor removing it.

So I dpkg forced uninstall MySql and backup `/var/lib/mysql` to a tar file.

To recover my data and perform a mysqldump, I tried to install MariaDB 10.3 and restore the MySQL database, but I couldn't restart the daemon.

From this, I created a whole new VM on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
apt update
apt install mysql-server
systemctl stop mysql
scp server:mysql.tar.gz .
tar xvzf mysql.tar.gz
chown -R mysql:mysql mysql
cp -r mysql/laravel /var/lib/mysql
systemctl start mysql
```

From `mysql` I can see my `lavael` schema, but it is empty. `show tables;` shows an empty set.

How can I restore this database?

Of course If I simply copy the backup to `/var/lib/mysql` I cannot start my daemon:

```
# systemctl start mysql
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Your backup was an entire MySQL folder, correct? Can you find and post the text in `my.cnf/my.ini` file in both of your backup and the from MySQL in your new VM?

Comment: I don't have the `my.ini` anymore as it was in `/etc/mysql`. However, I have a `auto.cnf` in the MySQL directory with : `[auto] server-uuid=cf826c8c...`

Comment: I remember doing something similar like [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/288861/191579).. basically; recreate table(s) in new database, discard tablespace, copy `.ibd` files into the data folder then import tablespace. If that's successful, dump the data and re-import to the working database.